# Problems animating a custom struct using the Unity Animation window

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, struct

I am looking to animate a custom struct in the Unity Animation window.

When a Vector3 is animated, the x, y and z components are grouped and can be accessed via a drop-down on the Vector3:

[image: Vector3]

I wish to replicate this behaviour and am able to do so by declaring the following struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyStructA
{
    public float x, y, z;
}
```

[image: MyStructA]

My problem is I don't want the fields to be named x, y and z - but when I change the names it appears to break the grouping in the Animation window:

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyStructB
{
    public float Foo, Bar, Baz;
}
```

[image: MStructB]

I am struggling to find documentation on this behaviour, or any ways to control it? Is there a custom Editor I can write to describe to the Animator how my struct should be displayed?

Comment: I have the same behaviour (2017.3.0.f3), I'm afraid is a problem caused by how Unity serializes the struct's fields and/or how they're read from the Animation Property window. I can't find either any informations about it online.